# sed replace anything after nth occurence

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am new in Bash scripting and have been searching for a proper answer to how can I use sed to replace anything after the nth occurence (not to replace the nth occurence).

For example, if I want to change anything that comes after the 2nd space, I'd have the following sentence as input: `Today is a good day` and the following sentence as result: `Today is a friday`

Any ideas?

Comment: But `good` is after 3rd space not 2nd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='Today is a good day'
echo "$s" | sed 's/^\(\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{3\}\)[^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+/\1fri/'
Today is a friday
```

Simplified using `-r`:

```
cho "$s" | sed -r 's/^((\S+\s+){3})\S+\s+/\1fri/'
Today is a friday
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd say this is way complex to a beginner!

Comment: @anubhava Could you plz give a bit description about the structure of sed in the first part of your answer?

Comment: Actually first and second seed command are same. Only difference is that first seed is using POSIX property `[[:blank:]]` which matches space or tab character. Without `-r` we need to escape brackets to capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `awk`

```
echo "Today is a good day" | awk '{print $1,$2,"a friday"}'
Today is a friday
```

This will keep the first two fields, and replace the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
 echo 'Today is a good day.' | sed 's/ /&\n/3; s/\n.*/friday/'
```

This consists of two commmands:

```
s/ /&\n/3       # inserts a \n after the third space
s/\n.*/friday/  # replaces \n and everything that comes after it with "friday"
```

This uses the fact that `\n` will never appear in a line -- something that makes `\n` great as a marker in sed scripts. `&` refers to the matched portion of the line.

Comment: I had thaught about the same but couldn't get it through.. your answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question being asked, this doesn't really even need sed or awk, if you're using Unix 7th Edition shell or a newer shell based on it like sh or bash.  Just use an unfortunately obscure feature of the set command:

```
$ set Today is a good day
$ echo $1 $2 "Friday"
Today is Friday
```

The original question asked about patterns, but the example offered has the pattern being just a single space.  The second occurrence of the space implicitly follows the second argument.  You can adapt it to "nth occurrence" using a little shell arithmetic, I imagine.

This set trick has been around a long time, even though I just recently discovered it.  An example of its use appears on page 136 of Kernighan and Pike's "The UNIX Programming Environment" (1984).  It works the same on Bash, and I would guess it must be present on any 7th Ed. shell derivative.